# JavaScript Audio Web APN

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-audio

I m working on a site that plays an audio using the navigator's control. I also added an input file. 
But if I change the the audio file (while another audio is playing) I want the navigator's player to play this audio instead not the previous one. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to check current one is paused, and then, on load new file - play it, if old one is not paused:

here is one hastily created example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="song">
      <audio id ='old-sound' controls>
        <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        <a href="1.mp3">Скачать name.mp3</a>
      </audio>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let _paused = document.querySelector("#old-sound").paused;

        let sound = document.createElement("audio");
        sound.id = "new-sound";
        sound.controls = "controls";
        sound.src = "2.mp3";
        sound.type = "audio/mpeg";

        let element = document.querySelector("#song");
        element.innerHTML = "";
        element.appendChild(sound);

        if (!_paused) document.querySelector("#new-sound").play();
      }, 5000);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```